# Working with sockets with multiprocessing + asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-sockets

I want to process clients in different processes asynchronously, that is, each process can process many client connections asynchronously. The code I have at the moment:

```
import os, socket
import asyncio

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

async def process_client(client: socket) -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    data = await loop.sock_recv(client, 256)

def main_process(q: Queue) -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    while True:
        try:
            client, addr = q.get(timeout=1)
            loop.create_task(process_client(client))
        except:
            pass

def main() -> None:
    server_ip = os.environ['SERVER_IP']
    server_port = int(os.environ['SEVER_PORT'])

    q = Queue()
    
    for _ in range(8):
        worker = Process(target=main_process, args=(q, ))
        worker.start()

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server:
        server.bind((server_ip, server_port))
        server.listen(100)

        while True:
            client, addr = server.accept()
            q.put((client, addr))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

create a task does not create a task because the while loop and q.get(timeout=1)  block the thread.  If the multiprocessing queue was asynchronous, then I would be able to do for example this: client, addr = await q.get()

Comment: Have you actually tested the above code ? Sockets aren't serializable so you cannot just put them on the queue anyway, at least not the way you expect them to.

Comment: Yes, I know that a socket is a kernel object that is only available in the process in which it appeared. I tested this code, just ran the task through ayncio.run and everything worked. It looks like queue multiprocessing does not only transfer data to processes, but also duplicates of kernel objects

Comment: That depends on the platform, at least on windows you need to call [socket.share](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.share) to do that, i think there's something similar for linux.

Comment: I have already said that the code works only synchronously, so I don't have to do this. Now the question is how to achieve asynchrony

Answer (score 0):

you can call a blocking function within an asyncio eventloop using [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

```py
client, addr = await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(q.get,timeout=1))
```

This needs to happen inside an async function so you need to define one.

```py
async def main_process_async(q: Queue):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    while True:
        try:
            client, addr = await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(q.get,timeout=1))
            loop.create_task(process_client(client))
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

def main_process(q: Queue) -> None:
    asyncio.run(main_process_async(q))
```

This may fail because you cannot serialize socket objects directly on all platforms, there are platform dependent methods for sharing sockets like `socket.share` for windows.

Comment: Thanks it really worked! But I think that await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(q.get,timeout=1)), timeout=1 is superfluous here. You can remove it and also remove the try block.

Comment: I use windows and everything works for me without socket.share.